# C Program sending a TCP RST to the Server

Tags: c, tcp

I need to simulate a TCP RST connection issue. For this purpose, I'd need to write a C Client that connects to a TCP Server and send a TCP RST connection.
I have found this sample code but on the Server side I don't see any Connection Reset traced. I'm not a expert on C so I wonder if anything is missing to send a RST Socket.

Any help?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main() {
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock == -1) {
    perror("Socket creation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // Replace with client IP
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(8080); // Replace with client port

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) != 0) {
    perror("Connection failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Close the socket without graceful termination to send RST
  close(sock);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there's any easy way to send a TCP reset packet from C code. The RST flag is used to indicate an error condition. Closing a socket isn't an error condition. (It just sends a FIN flag.)

Comment: Use  Wireshark to see what gets send by your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between `socket()` & `connect()` you need to set the linger option. If the linger option is set and you exit a reset is send. `close()` usually starts an orderly shutdown with a “FIN” packet.

```
    struct linger sl;
    bzero(&sl, sizeof(sl));
    sl.l_onoff = 1;
    sl.l_linger = 0;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &sl, sizeof(sl)) < 0)
        perror("setsockopt");
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I've just found one example (but in python) which does exactly this.

Comment: Only if you set the timeout to zero.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks my intention was fo it to be `sl.l_linger = 0;`